# How can I use user32.dll's GetSystemMenu with monodevelop C# on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

I have to use C# with MonoDevelop to create a same software (which is on Windows) on Linux (Ubuntu)
But in app on Windows, I using the native API from User32.dll

DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

How can I do the same methods with monodevelop C# on Linux?

Comment: Please use code formatting to format code. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you expect `GetSystemMenu` to do under Linux?

Comment: My program is GUI Interface program and it must run same on Ubuntu, so i need to use user32.dll's some APIs on Ubuntu's MonoDevelop

Comment: user32.dll is a windows specific dll. So on linux, there is nothing to import. You can't do windows native specific commands on Linux

Comment: What you need to know is what is a linux equivalent workflow that will let you do what you are trying to do.